# Is asking to provide an unorthodox answer wrong on the StackExchange sites?

Tags: discussion, answers

This is the question in question: [How to embed special markers into the code listing that will mark certain parts of code to be colored using a custom scheme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153819/how-to-embed-special-markers-into-the-code-listing-that-will-mark-certain-parts/153828?noredirect=1#comment352021_153828).

Please follow the discussion in the comments for the answer by Jubobs. I appreciate his effort, but I am confused by his claim that asking for an unmaintainable solution is wrong? Is StackExchange only about finding the orthodox solutions regardless of time it takes to implement them?

Just to make it clear - this is not a complaint. I am just curious. Once again I appreciate the work done by Jubobs to write such a detailed and lengthy solution.

Comment: I think what Jubobs meant is that we don't email people solutions, and we're not rent-a-coder either.  He seemed a bit irked that you were saying "That's nice, but could you give me more?  Here's my personal email address if you're not comfortable posting it here."  He's right; StackExchange doesn't work that way.

Comment: I see. I must have misunderstood his comment.

Comment: Also note that "unmaintainable" and "unorthodox" really aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are perfectly within your rights to ask for a solution that others consider unorthodox, unmaintainable, etc.

Another user is completely within *his* rights to refuse to provide such a solution and to instead only provide a solution that they feel is maintainable or otherwise preferable.

SO is about finding high quality answers to questions in which the answers are encouraged to be those that will be the most helpful to readers of the question.  Users are encouraged to vote on answers not just based on correctness, but usefulness/helpfulness.  If someone feels that an answer is correct, but undesirable, harmful, etc. they can and should downvote it.